# is there a way find all coordinates inside a polygon and use each points to get their value (radiance)

Tags: postgis, raster2pgsql

I have this GeoTIFF file that I acquired in [NOAA](https://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/viirs/download_dnb_composites.html) ( [Tarball contains the TIFF file VIIRS](https://data.ngdc.noaa.gov/instruments/remote-sensing/passive/spectrometers-radiometers/imaging/viirs/dnb_composites/v10//201901/vcmcfg/SVDNB_npp_20190101-20190131_75N060E_vcmcfg_v10_c201905201300.tgz) ) that has a light intensity in each area in the world. Its categorize per tile. I used the one that covers Asian countries (Am from Philippines). I successfully import it to PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension using raster2pgsql.

```bsh
sudo raster2pgsql -s 4326 -c -b 1 -R -N -3.40282346638529e+038 -I -M NOAAMapLight/2019/SVDNB_npp_20190101-20190131_75N060E_vcmcfg_v10_c201905201300/SVDNB_npp_20190101-20190131_75N060E_vcmcfg_v10_c201905201300.avg_rade9h.tif -F -t  256x256 public.viirs_2019_01 | psql -h localhost -d CarlPostGIS -U carl
```

So the issue is that I have points that creates a polygon of each community in a City (Mandaluyong City its from the Philippines). Some of these polygon is too small to actually get the value inside of it. So i was thinking if there's a way to find each coordinates inside the polygon and get their respective value. Because I tried using these query

```sql
SELECT ST_SummaryStatsAgg(ST_Clip(rast,
ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((coord))'),4326),-3.40282346638529e+038, TRUE), 1, TRUE, 1) as values
FROM public.viirs_2019_01 WHERE
ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((coord))'),4326), rast)
```

and as I said there are some polygons that are just too small to find its value.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There's literally an infinity of possible coordinates inside a polygon (if you don't specify a precision) so I'm not sure that it is the best way to do it. In your case it simply looks like the precision of your raster is not enough to use it at the neighborhood scale (See here :https://utility.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/Utilities/PrintingTools_GPServer/x_____x6hpOQBSXF-KTiDcNDMjzkw..x_____x_ags_f3cb5a9e-e8db-11e9-b9d0-22000a05be52.png).

Comment: @LéoM is it possible to get at least some points inside the polygon let say about 50 points? 
By the way, the link doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for the link, see here : https://i.imgur.com/rUQ2c4z.png
If you want to generate the points randomly, use https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html

Comment: @LéoM I tried ST_GeneratePoints to create random points inside a polygon but when i try to double check if the generated points where in did inside the polygon it returns false. see here: https://imgur.com/a/whu49gE

Comment: You are creating a buffer around the polygon (St_Buffer) of 1 unit so you'll have points outside the geometry. Furthermore, I think that ST_Within doesn't accept geometries collections (http://www.h2gis.org/docs/dev/ST_Within/), you have to test individually each points.